# Regex distinguish < in logical operations and parenthesis pairs

Tags: regex, vim

I am coding a plugin that automatically adds spaces around symbols, I use the search function to locate symbols that match the regular expression and then modify. But I can't write an expression to distinguish the `<` in

```py
#include<stdio.h>
a<b
a<b>
a<v and c>d
```

it should be

```py
#include<stdio.h>
a < b
a<b>
a < v and c > d
```

but it will be

```py
#include < stdio.h>
a < b
a < b>
a < v and c > d
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me write this expression.

Thanks.

I used `[^ <']<[^ <=']` for search the `<`, but obviously this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If lookarounds are supported, you could use

```
(?<!\S)([^\s<>+])([<>])([^\s<>]+)(?!\S)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `([^\s<>+])` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non whitespace chars other than `<` `>`
- `([<>])` Capture **group 2**, capture either `<` or `>`
- `([^\s<>]+)` Capture **group 3**, match 1+ non whitespace chars other than `<` `>`
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ctSrx8/1)

In the replacement use the 3 capture groups with a space between the group values.

```
$1 $2 $3
```

The output after the replacement:

```
#include<stdio.h>
a < b
a<b>
a < v and c > d
```

---

In `vim` using the very magic mode `\v`

```
:%s/\v\S@<!([^\s<>+])([<>])([^\s<>]+)\S@!/\1 \2 \3/g
```

[image]